# Empty string as output when PHP AES 256 Decryption is used

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

I have a problem, I need to decrypt a string but always I get an empty string as output. My code is bellow:

```
$key = base64_encode(hex2bin('6E792B88F319E6D24254445D534DFB12B29BBAAEA44901A8E3DB9A0F35BFAFB8')); //Key in Hex
$encstr = base64_decode("69hSr72tA958CX87ZDMPAOYfS8aMz4oF7/7TvxdPnL4="); //Cypher Text in Base 64
$output = openssl_decrypt($encstr, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0);

echo "Plain Text=".$output;
```

Anybody could help me please to know what is wrong?

If I do it on a web page I get the desire output (without IV):

[Decryption OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0tPs.png)

Comment: You only can decrypt with the key that you used for encryption.

Comment: 1. [openssl_error_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php) 2. The first error is about key length, drop the `base64_encode()` on the key. 3. The next error is a bad decrypt, probably because you're missing the IV.

Comment: Also, make sure PHP error reporting is turned on, and instead of `echo` with concatenating, use `var_dump()` on the result to see what is actually being returned.

Comment: The general issue with your code is the AES mode you re using: **CBC**. This mode requires an initialization vector (IV) that was used on encryption side. You need to provide this IV as last parameter in your openssl_decrypt function. Btw: in most times the IV is the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext, sometimes an IV filled with 16 x00's is used (what is unsecure).

Comment: Actually the key is too long for AES-256 and the specification of an IV for the CBC mode is missing, but `openssl_decrypt()` and the website apply the same (bad) logic: They silently truncate the key to 32 bytes and implicitly use an IV consisting of 0x00 values only.